# CCFL wire polarity; any considerations?

Tags: led, power, lcd, display, ccfl

Are there any considerations for the polarity of wires on a CCFL tube?

I am converting a monitor from 120vAC to 12vDC using a generic inverter (AVT4029; also have AVT4168 not pictured) and LCD driver board.  The CCFL tubes are encased in the assembled display (Samsung LTM230HT01) and I would like to avoid further disassembly for risk of damage.  The CCFL wiring harness is similar to the standard small CCFL connector found in laptops, except the connector has 4 pins on each harness (connector: YEON-HO 35001HS-04L), 2x harnesses on the display so 4 lamps.  Pairs are red/white and blue/gray.  I cut the connector in half so it fits into the generic inverter.  The wires are all of the same gauge.

[image]

Edited to add:  the spec sheet for the panel is here http://www.spectrah.com/product/lcd_panel/samsung_lcd_panel/Samsung-LTM230HT01.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCFL's like NEON tubes, enjoy AC current with light emanation in each polarity.  Each tube is rated in mA and power rating.  ( keep it on dim to extend life of CCFL and your eyes)

Comment: Pulling the bulb specs to ensure it matches the generic inverter seems like the next step. ty.